# Python - split website URL with starting and ending condition

Tags: python, split

I've extracted a column with website links from a data frame.

```
tweets = csv_doc.Tweet
URL = [re.findall(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+',x) for x in tweets]
```

Now I want just to select all but `http(s)//:` and `'`, which are the limits from the information I need.
Example:
Is shown: `https://t(.)co/V3aoj9RUh4`  (parenthesis added to avoid links)
Is needed:  `'t.co'.`

I think I could do it directly using split when using the variable `URL` instead of using `findall`
However, I tried to do it separately first:
`[re.split(r'//\?\'',x) for x in tweets]`

I don't get any error, but nothing is shown on screen.

`r'//` means it split the string starting with '//'

`\?` means the length of the string is unknown

`\'` means it ends with "'"

What was wrong here? How can I prove that by just save the main part of the URL?

Once this is split, how can I group and count?
I want to get a list of the number of times that a link appears.
`group()` and `count()` don't work in lists.

Comment: Why not just [parse it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-parsing)?

Comment: Note that the pattern has a character class with a range `$-_` that matches from ASCII index 36 - 95 which can also match `'` and `?` Pehaps you meant `$\-_`

Comment: @Sayse, how would you do it? ````u = [urlparse(x) for x in URL]````?? I am trying like this I am getting an error because of being a list (again)

Comment: @Thefourthbird it works! By deleting also ````http[s]?:```` I get almost the right answer: ```` '//t.co'```` How would you also delete '//' without getting an error? Thanks.

Comment: You are using re.findall which will return the value of the capture group. If you don't want the `http://` part, you can capture the rest of the pattern in a capture group, see https://regex101.com/r/IEa8Ta/1 Not sure what the custom logic is, but you might rewrite the pattern as `http[s]?://((?:[a-zA-Z0-9$_@.&+!*(),-]|%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F])+)`

Comment: @icatalan - Just `urlparse(URL)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
#create an empty dictionary to store the counts
counts = {}

#loop over the URLs in your list
for tweet in tweets:

    #match everything after http(s):// up to the next '/'
    matches = re.findall(r'http[s]?://([^\/]*)',tweet)
    for match in matches:
        counts[match] = counts.get(match,0) + 1

#print out the number of counts of each domain
for domain,frequency in counts.items():
    print("{} {}".format(domain,frequency))
```

Comment: thank you very much. I've tried to do the same as list comprehension but ````findall```` doesn't work well, so I took the same solution you suggested!

Comment: how would you add an exception to the regex code? I want to look for all the http(s):// except those which have 'www.': ````matches = re.findall(r'http[s]?://([^\/]*)(?!www.)',tweet)```` does not work as far as I tired. Thanks

Comment: I would do that as a separate filtering step, along the lines of `if (!match.startswith('www')):`

Comment: isn't there any way of writing exceptions? I thought ````?!```` makes that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `split`, and set the maxsplit to 2. The `url` will then be the last item in the list, which you can access with `[-1]`:

```
url = 'https://twitter.com/V3aoj9RUh4'
url.split('/', 2)[-1]
```

Result: `twitter.com/V3aoj9RUh4`

For an url in a string first `split` the string:

```
text = 'This is a text https://twitter.com/V3aoj9RUh4 nice'
[url.split('/', 2)[-1] for url in text.split() if 'http' in url]
```

This would make:

```
URL = [url.split('/', 2)[-1] for x in tweets for url in x.split() if 'http' in url]
```

Comment: this only may work for some cases in the list as I proved before writing. I get in some cases the content of the tweet. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer to address this issue.